# Rear view mirror damage

Tags: wing-mirrors

I drove a bit blind this morning and ended up scratching my driver side rear view mirror with the next vehicle’s passenger side rear view mirror. I was turning right when the other car was waiting to turn right. 
I did not see any immediate damage to the other car rear view mirror. I was in such a hurry I could not check in the busy traffic.

My car rear view mirror is fine. What are the chances that the other car passenger side rear view mirror would have been damaged?

Comment: Chances are low - however if you did not stop to check, then presumably you also did not stop to exchange details with the other driver? 'Failing to stop at the scene of an accident' is a criminal offence in many jurisdictions...

Comment: True. I note that. How do I get in touch? Should I register with the police?

Comment: Did the other car also drive off? I can't really give you legal advice...

Comment: in which country did it happen?

Comment: UK. The other driver did not bother at that point in time. I just called the police and reported the incident. thanks all

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about vehicle maintenance or repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mirror-to-Mirror impacts like this are quite common - and if it did enough to damage *yours* then it probably did enough to damage *theirs* as well but from how you describe it the damage is very slight in any case.

Failure to stop at an accident is indeed an offence in the UK (under section 170 of the Road Traffic Act), however for the sort of contact you describe it's actually extremely common for one or both parties to keep on going. It sounds like you reported it to the police inside the requisite 24 hours though so that should cover off that issue anyway.

Comment: yup. all good. I visited the local police station too and they also said its not something to report on, as the impact is on rear-view mirrors.